# How do I prove this equation by mathematical induction?

Tags: proof-verification, summation, induction

I am new to induction and am stuck on the following formula. I have completed the base induction step, but I don't even really know where to start when proving $P(k+1)$. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks! (P.S. this is for all integers $n \geq 0$).

$P(n)$: $$\sum_{j=0}^n (4j+1) = 2n^2+3n+1$$

$P(k+1)$: $$\sum_{j=0}^{k+1} (4j+1) = 2(k+1)^2+3(k+1)+1$$

Comment: Try the induction step by separating the $k+1$ term from the sum and then use the hypothesis. I would post an answer but I'm on my phone...

Comment: $$\sum_{j=0}^{k+1} (4j+1) = 2k^2+3k+1+4(k+1)+1=2 (k^2+2k+1)+3k+3+1=2 (k+1)^2+3(k+1)+1$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have $\sum_{j=0}^k(4j+1) = 2k^2 + 3k + 1$, so when you take $\sum_{j=0}^{k+1}(4j+1)$ you are just adding one extra term: $4(k+1)+1$. Add this to your previous total and see if you can factor the resulting polynomial into the desired form.

Comment: I tried this and ended up getting the factored form (2k+3)(k+2), I am not sure if I did something wrong or if that is correct and I am overlooking something?

Comment: You are on the right track, but picked the wrong factored form! See (the delightfully-named) Thomas Shelby's comment above (which ought really to have been an answer). Why is this clear? Well, you know what to aim for, so (in rough) you can really work your way in from both sides and meet in the middle.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**:

Rewrite the inductive hypothesis in function of $k+1$:
$$2k^2+3k+1=2(k+1)^2-(k+1).$$

Answer (score 0):

Try this:
$$\sum_{j=0}^n (4j+1) = 2n^2+3n+1$$

First, note that in the n+1 case the difference on the Left is 4(n+1)+1=4n+5. Secondly, the right hand side has difference 4n+2+3= 4n+5 .These are equal, so they change by the same amount, when the variable changes by 1. Therefore, they are equal for any natural number n, greater than a proven base case.